# What's wrong with Genymotion?

Tags: android, emulation, genymotion, libc, renderscript

I am using Genymotion Android emulator. On Android 4+ real device my app works fine, but when I use emulator I get this:

```
0-03 10:59:30.747 1562-1562/eu.mdaa E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
10-03 10:59:30.755 1562-1562/eu.mdaa E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
10-03 10:59:30.771 1562-1562/eu.mdaa E/RenderScript_jni: No GC methods
10-03 10:59:30.775 1562-1586/eu.mdaa E/RenderScript: Couldn't load libRSSupportIO.so
10-03 10:59:30.779 1562-1586/eu.mdaa A/libc: Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL) at 0x97466b72 (code=2), thread 1586 (eu.mdaa)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the crash was caused by using x86 emulator. BuildTools 23.0.3 should have this fixed though.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like your app isn't including libRSSupportIO.so, but is saying that it does use it. How are you using RS in your app?